# Convergence of $\int x_n \to \int x$ implies that product converges too

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a quick question I have as a thought in a proof I have, I have tried to look it up but I couldn't find it. Assume we know that $x_n\in L^p$ and $\int x_n$ converges to $\int x$, does this imply that $\int x_n f$ converges to $\int x f$ with $f\in L^p$ or $L^q$, with $1/p+1/q=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Take a non-zero function $x$ with $\int x = 0$ and set $x_n = n \, x$. Then, $\int x_n = 0 \to 0 = \int x$, but with $f = x$ or $f = \mathrm{sign}(x)$, we get $\int x \, f \ne 0$  and, thus, $\int x_n \, f = n \, \int x \, f \not\to \int x \, f$.

Comment: Drats =/ Thank you for the information though!